# Badge number won't clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, badge

I'm not sure what I changed in my app, but Im not able to clear the badges number anymore.

I put code the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

in:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I also tried:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

It just wont work, even though it did before, please advice

full code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    //Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];

    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    //application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` that way it'll only get cleared on launching the app.

Have you tried killing the app from the multitasking menu and launching it again?

Also try and move `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` .

Answer (score 0):

Set it to -1 like this:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

or like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];
```